# EF. AutoFac. Constantly got error DBContext has been disposed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first, autofac

Initial data. Code First, Autofac

Before was Linq2Sql and the entire data layer was in the main project.
I rewrote all on EF CodeFirst.
Now I keep getting an error: DBContext has been disposed

There is a class:

```
public class DataManager: IDataManager    
{
    private IModelDataContextWrapper _dataContext;

    public IAuditRepository Audits { get; set; }
    public ICDMRepository CDMs { get; set; }
    public ICommandRepository Commands { get; set; }
    public IMonitoringRepository Monitorings { get; set; }
    public IRoleRepository Roles { get; set; }
    public ISettingRepository Settings { get; set; }
    public IUserRepository Users { get; set; }

    public DataManager(IModelDataContextWrapper dataContext)    
    {    
        _dataContext = dataContext;    
    }

    public IModelDataContextWrapper DataContext    
    {    
        get    
        {    
            return _dataContext;    
        }    
    }

    public void Dispose()    
    {    
        if (_dataContext != null)    
        {    
            _dataContext.Dispose();    
            _dataContext = null;    
        }
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);    
    }

    public void SaveChanges()    
    {    
        try    
        {    
            DataContext.SaveChanges();    
        }    
        catch (Exception ex)    
        {    
            string err = string.Format("exception: {0} stacktrace: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);

            Logger.Instance.WriteLine(err);    
        }    
    }    
}

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository    
{    
    private readonly IModelDataContext _context;

    public UserRepository(IModelDataContext context)    
    {    
        _context = context;    
    }
}
```

Autofac registration:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.RegisterType<ModelDataContext>().As<IModelDataContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<ModelDataContextWrapper>().As<IModelDataContextWrapper>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<ArchiveModelDataContext>().As<IArchiveModelDataContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<DataManager>().As<IDataManager>().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<AuditRepository>().As<IAuditRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<CommandRepository>().As<ICommandRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<CDMRepository>().As<ICDMRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<MonitoringRepository>().As<IMonitoringRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<RoleRepository>().As<IRoleRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<SettingRepository>().As<ISettingRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<ThemedViewEngine>();

builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

IContainer container = builder.Build();

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
var lifetimeScope = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ILifetimeScope>();

lifetimeScope.InjectProperties(Membership.Provider);

lifetimeScope.InjectProperties(Roles.Provider);
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use .InstancePerRequest(); in web context.
And you need avoid IQueryable in you view, be sure you have ToList() or request trigger in your controller and not in your view

Updated:

```
        builder.RegisterType<ModelDataContextWrapper>()
            .As<IModelDataContextWrapper >()
            .InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: At first it was so, but it does not work   builder.RegisterType<ModelDataContext>().As<IModelDataContext>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

Comment: InstancePerRequest and not InstancePerHttp‌​Request, to avoid instance for static resources, and just on DbContext, not on all, you can see an exemple of what is use on [GitHub](https://github.com/Nono31/Pixel.Sample)

Comment: InstancePerRequest abcent in list of methods. Only InstancePerLifetimeScope. The project is MVC 4.

Comment: [InstancePerRequest](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-request) Wich version of autofac do you use

Comment: Version 3.0.0.0. Thanks. I think I found problem. Problem in my Singleton class.

Comment: You're welcome, you can also use .SingleInstance() for singleton